# Unhandled exception at line 21, column 1 in http://localhost:7454/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js 0x800a1391 - 'jQuery' is undefined

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

```
@model Test_15.Models.EmployeeViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Modal";    
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="width:40%;margin-top:2%">

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">

<div class="modal-dialog">

<div class="modal-content">

<div class="modal-header">

<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>

<h3 class="modal-title">Technotips MVC</h3>

</div>

<div class="modal-body">

<form id="myForm">

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentId, ViewBag.DepartmentList as SelectList, "--select--", new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Name" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Address" })

</form>

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">

<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>

<input type="reset" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" />

</div>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<script>
debugger;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
debugger;
alert("I want this to appear after the modal has opened!");
var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
URL: "/Home/Index",
data: myformdata,
success: function () {
("#myModal").modal("hide");
}
})
})
})
</script>
```

This is my index file. In this I am calling a modal, and then in modal there are 2 buttons, and on the submit button it is not calling the script. Applying debugger it says `Unhandled exception at line 21, column 1 in http://localhost:7454/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined`.
Please help.

Comment: Most likely you're loading jQuery twice (in the parent page & inside the modal), because you're putting it in the proper order. If you have loaded 2 jQuery files, remove the jQuery `<script>` tag inside the modal.

Comment: Hey @TetsuyaYamamoto, thanks for the prompt response. The issue was with the jquery files. It is resolved now. Thanks :)